# Converting raised position to binary

Tags: python-3.x, binary, braille

I am working on going from o-string binary to Unicode, part of this process requires converting Raised Position to Binary. I can't seem to be able to get it done. The doc test will explain what needs to be performed.

I have provided my code below but it is nowhere close to getting the correct answer.

def raisedpos_to_binary(s):
    ''' (str) -> str
    Convert a string representing a braille character in raised-position
    representation  into the binary representation.
    TODO: For students to complete.

```
>>> raisedpos_to_binary('')
'00000000'
>>> raisedpos_to_binary('142536')
'11111100'
>>> raisedpos_to_binary('14253678')
'11111111'
>>> raisedpos_to_binary('123')
'11100000'
>>> raisedpos_to_binary('125')
'11001000'
'''

res = ''
lowest_value = '00000000'
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == i:
        lowest_value = lowest_value.replace('0', '1')
return lowest_value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can create a set (converted to integers) of the single digits and then produce '1' or '0' iterating over a range of 1..8, eg:

```
def raisedpos_to_binary(digits):
    raised = {int(digit) for digit in digits}
    return ''.join('1' if n in raised else '0' for n in range(1, 9))
```

Tests:

```
for test in ['', '142536', '14253678', '123', '125']:
    print(test, '->', raised_pos_to_binary(test))
```

Gives you:

```
 -> 00000000
142536 -> 11111100
14253678 -> 11111111
123 -> 11100000
125 -> 11001000
```

So in full, your module should contain:

```
def raisedpos_to_binary(digits):
    """
    >>> raisedpos_to_binary('')
    '00000000'
    >>> raisedpos_to_binary('142536')
    '11111100'
    >>> raisedpos_to_binary('14253678')
    '11111111'
    >>> raisedpos_to_binary('123')
    '11100000'
    >>> raisedpos_to_binary('125')
    '11001000'
    """

    raised = {int(digit) for digit in digits}
    return ''.join('1' if n in raised else '0' for n in range(1, 9))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Then run your script using:

```
python your_script.py -v
```

Comment: The doctests for '142536', '125', and '142353678' still aren't working

Comment: Works fine for me (*5 passed and 0 failed.*)  - have you made sure to use the above code? How are you running the doctests?

Comment: Yes the same code! I'm running the doctest by importing it and then running it as I did above

Comment: @MatthewTabet have you got exactly what I've added to the answer?

Comment: Hi John, yes I have exactly what is there and it still doesn't work